# Was the Ram Turbo the only 3rd party Interface 2 ROM cartridge interface for the ZX Spectrum or were there others?

Tags: hardware, zx-spectrum, game-cartridge

One of the original Sinclair peripherals for the ZX Spectrum was the [Interface 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Interface_2) which provided joystick ports and also a slot for ROM cartridges:
[image: ZX Interface 2]

The cartridges did not catch on though and only about 10 titles were ever released.

But before it was known that it would be a flop, at least one third party company released a compatible ROM cartridge interface, the Ram Turbo:

[image: Ram Turbo]

When I was a kid I bought a joystick and cartridge adaptor for my original 48K Speccy by mail order from the UK. I can't remember which brand it was except that it was not the official Sinclair one. Maybe it was the Ram Turbo. But were there others on the market as well? I can't find a definitive list and only some modern retro-era addons are turning up in my Google quest.

Comment: A bit of trivia: I bought a new Ram Turbo around 1991. It had the little hatch for the cartridge and two rows of solder dots on the circuit board below the hatch, but the cartridge connector had been left out, and wasn't mentioned in the manual or on the box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently, it was not the only one. I own a Kempston Pro Joystick Interface, which has one joystick port for Kempston/Cursor protocols, two ports for Sinclair 1/2 protocols, and a "games cartridge port". (the epoxy is an attempt of mine to hold in place the plastic part of the edge connector).

[image: Kemspton Pro Joystick Interface, upper view]

[image: Kemspton Pro Joystick Interface, lower view]

Comment: Because it was just a simple edge connector and minimal chip select logic, it would have been quite cheap to add this feature to an existing device. If it hadn't been such a short lived idea I 'd expect them to have become ubiquitous in such devices.