# How many commercial Spectrum ROM cartridges were released?

Tags: history, zx-spectrum, game-cartridge

According to [this site](http://www.fruitcake.plus.com/Sinclair/Interface2/Cartridges/Interface2_RC_Cartridges.htm), Sinclair released a total of ten titles on cartridge: all games that were popular on cassette, and all in 1983, the year the Interface 2 was released.

I know the cartridges flopped pretty quickly, largely because most Spectrum users weren't willing to pay thrice the price of a cassette just for an instant load. Still, Sinclair promoted them in the Spectrum+ manual (1984) and, per [this q](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15691/), there were third-party cartridge interfaces in the wild around that time.

**Did any other company release Spectrum software on cartridge?** If so, how many titles in total were released?

I'm particularly looking for releases while the Speccy games market was still current, so before 1995 (I think that's a fair cut-off), but I'll also accept later commercial offerings for the clone market(s), or a reliable source saying no such cartridges were made.

Comment: There were only the ten listed on the Wikipedia page in terms of official releases.

Comment: Official Sinclair, 11, counting with the diagnostic test used by authorised service centres. https://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/23089/Sinclair-ZX-Spectrum-Test-Cartridge/ .

Comment: Don't forget the Timex cartridges https://k1.spdns.de/Vintage/Sinclair/Software/Timex%202068%20Cartridges/

Comment: The Timex cartridges are totally different hardware-wise and software-wise. I asked a question here some years back.

Comment: @hippietrail Thanks. If I read it right, one of the answers to your question had a comment about "Maybe 15-20 titles" being released for the Speccy. The plot thickens...